# error borders not fit into the container- flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter now I'm creating a login page for my app. when I submit empty fields, I'm getting this issue. it's not fit into the container. struggling to solve this problem. how to overcome this issue. appreciate your help on this. below I have provided my email field code with the picture of the issue I'm facing.

[image]

```
GlassmorphicContainer(
            borderRadius: 30,
            blur: 40,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            border: 2,
            linearGradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                colors: [
                  Color(0xFFffffff).withOpacity(0.1),
                  Color(0xFFFFFFFF).withOpacity(0.05),
                ],
                stops: [
                  0.1,
                  1,
                ]),
            borderGradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: [
                Color(0xFFffffff).withOpacity(0.2),
                Color((0xFFFFFFFF)).withOpacity(0.2),
              ],
            ),
            height: 50,
            width: 300,
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: emailEditingController,
              enabled: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    // borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    //   color: textWhite,
                    // ),
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: textWhite),
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                ),
                //isDense: true,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 30, 10, 0),

                hintText: "Email/ Username",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: textWhite, fontFamily: "Roboto", fontSize: 14),
              ),
              style: TextStyle(color: buttontext),
              validator: (String? UserName) {
                if (UserName != null && UserName.isEmpty) {
                  return "Email can't be empty";
                }
                return null;
              },
              onChanged: (String? text) {
                email = text!;
                // print(email);
              },
              onSaved: (value) {
                loginUserData['email'] = value!;
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give some padding for container

```
Container(
     padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child:TextFormField()
      )
```

Comment: Undefined name 'EdgeInstes'.

Comment: i have updated the code try now

Answer (score 1):

Increase the **height** and **width** of the **container** or add **padding** into the `Container`

```
Container(
        height: 100.0, // height
        width: 400.0, // Width
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), // Padding
        child: TextFormField(),
      ),
```